# Downloads from Google Cloud Storage take much longer at above 100ms simulated ping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am currently using The GCS C# library inside of Unity to download some files for the game I work on. As part of testing, we use Clumsy to simulate network conditions and have noticed fromof that testing and when using external testers that downloading objects from GCS that at about ~100ms+ ping downloads take much longer (from within a second to 1 minute+). I have confirmed that this delay isn't being caused by my code as far as I can tell (Timestamps on both sides of the call to the library)

Does anyone have any ideas of what can cause this and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: If the motorway is gridlocked your car won’t move. If the network is busy or slower or both. So will your download be

Answer (score -1):

The ping command uses the ICMP protocol. Google Cloud Storage does not support ICMP. What you are pinging is an endpoint (frontend) before Cloud Storage.

Since Cloud Storage implements the HTTP protocol, use an HTTP testing tool.

ICMP is a best-effort protocol and endpoints are not required to respond at all. When they respond will be at their convenience which might be delayed for busy frontends.